# Too Many DML Statements : 1

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have this code :

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static Boolean upsertPassengerList(List<requestWrapper> requests){
        List<cms_Passenger_list__c> passengerList = new List<cms_Passenger_list__c>();
        for(requestWrapper r : requests){
            cms_Passenger_list__c p = new cms_Passenger_list__c();
            p.cms_Contact__c = r.contactId;
            p.cms_Travel__c = r.travelId;
            if(r.checked){
                p.cms_Status__c = 'Show';
            }else{
                p.cms_Status__c = 'No Show';
            }
            passengerList.add(p);
        }
        upsert passengerList;
        return true;
    }
```

JS Code:

```
   onSaveRecords(){
        upsertPassengerList({'requests' : this.upsertObject}).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log('error on save');
        })
    }
```

What am I missing? The method is getting called from an LWC and I can safely say that all the parameters are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remove cacheable = false from your method and it will solve your issue

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean upsertPassengerList(List<requestWrapper> requests){
        List<cms_Passenger_list__c> passengerList = new List<cms_Passenger_list__c>();
        for(requestWrapper r : requests){
            cms_Passenger_list__c p = new cms_Passenger_list__c();
            p.cms_Contact__c = r.contactId;
            p.cms_Travel__c = r.travelId;
            if(r.checked){
                p.cms_Status__c = 'Show';
            }else{
                p.cms_Status__c = 'No Show';
            }
            passengerList.add(p);
        }
        upsert passengerList;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Tried it. Still the same.

Comment: Add your js code as well. How you are calling this method

Comment: Added the JS Code.

Comment: This error mostly comes when you try to do dml in @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true) methods.

Comment: yeah I have read that one up, but I am now stuck and can't find the thing that I am missing. Must be something obvious I don't know.

Comment: Is this the only method in your LWC? Paste the whole code so it will be easy to find the cause.

Comment: It worked suddenly without me doing any change. I think its something inside cache of chrome :(

Comment: Yup that might be the reason.